# connect with service running on host from docker container

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, neo4j

I have done ssh port forwarding which listens to 2000 in my local. So the service is running on localhost:2000, it is Neo4J server. In my local, I am able to connect with Neo4J using Neo4J desktop by giving `bolt://localhost:2000` and can look at the datas.

but i am not able to connect with host bolt://localhost:2000 in docker container.

I looked at the answers here

[From inside of a Docker container, how do I connect to the localhost of the machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319662/from-inside-of-a-docker-container-how-do-i-connect-to-the-localhost-of-the-mach)

I added extra hosts in docker-compose.yml

```
flask_service:
    build:
      context: ./project
      dockerfile: my_dockerfile
    container_name: flask_container
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    ports:
      - 5000:5000
    extra_hosts:
      - "myhost:175.1.344.136"
```

**175.1.344.136 being my host IP**
and I have used both `bolt://175.1.344.136:2000` and `bolt://myhost:2000` inside container but it is not connecting. Also i want to know which is the right way `bolt://175.1.344.136:2000` or `bolt://myhost:2000`

I get an error

```
2021-05-25T10:53:55+0000.060 [INFO] neo4j_proxy.__init__:74 (8:Thread-11) - NEO4J endpoint: bolt://myhost:2000
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/neobolt/direct.py", line 831, in _connect
    s.connect(resolved_address)
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

I am using MacOs, Please help me resolve this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi, can you provide the whole docker-compose.yml file?

Comment: @utnaf i have updated the description

Comment: I would try to use `myhost:127.0.0.1` in the extra_hosts and use `bolt://myhost:2000`. Not really sure, I need time to give it a try

Comment: @utnaf tried doing that. still having same problem

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: @utnaf i have updated that in description

Answer (score -1):

you need to use the container service name **neo4j** and default port **7687** to use inside the same docker host.

> bolt://neo4j:7687

```
version: "3.8"
services:
    neo4j:
        image: neo4j:3.4.4-enterprise
        ports:
            - 7474:7474
            - 7687:7687
    my_service:
        build:
          context: .
        environment:
          DATABASE_URL: "bolt://neo4j:7687"
```

Comment: i want to use neo4j, which is running in my host at port 2000. not of the container. solution you have suggested is by creating new container for neo4J, which is not the solution for my problem. if i have miss read it. Please correct me

Comment: use bolt://{IP}:{NEO4J_PORT} - bolt://175.1.344.136:2000 
vrtify the network inside for the docker container.